# Client side signing of a file(.exe,.dll,.jar..) using CA issued certificate and signtool

Tags: digital-signature, code-signing

In a current project we have purchased certificate from a trusted CA and have installed in a host, sign tool is also installed in the same host.

All the files which we develop(jar,dll,apk,exe etc..,) needs to be signed, so we use the certificate and sign tool hosted in a central server.

When ever a developer wants to get his file signed , he will upload the file to the remote host where the Certificate and sign tool resides and signed file is downloaded.

Now since the file size is increasing day by day we will not be able to upload the entire file to a remote server to get is signed, is there a way to sign the file at client side and send only the hash value back to server for reference???

Comment: You should ask the support team of the product you use for signing.

Answer (score 3):

In theory, what you're asking for is possible: code signing basically is just signing a file hash so there is no reason why you have to do that at the same place the hash is calculated.

In practice, though, I'm not aware of any way you can do that without writing your own code signing code - something that you should really not consider. It would be a delicate problem because you'd have to secure the system very tightly.

That being said, I cannot really imagine a setup where uploading your code to a signing server would be impossible or even very difficult. I suggest you concentrate on that aspect of your problem instead.

**Edit**: In view of Jonathan's answer, I think I have to add a word of warning about trying to change existing code to implement such system.

First, it can be done. In fact, after checking my own (read: the code I use, which is professionally maintained, and not any code I wrote myself) code-signing libraries, it wouldn't be too hard (at least not at the code-signing level).

That out of the way, you need to consider the consequences: first, the tools and library you use would then immediately stop being supported by your provider (whoever they are): if there is any bug in it that is fixed at a later date, you'll have to implement the patch yourself (assuming you can). This is incredibly uncomfortable from an operational point of view.

Second, writing crypto code is HARD and writing a **safe** crypto-based product is even harder. While it can be quite interesting to do so "for the fun", a professional, production-ready system needs much more resources than a single person: it's really a team effort that requires formalized testing.

So, given that your issue seems to be that you have a single instance of a problem (your code base is so big that you're having issue uploading it to the server), I think it's a problem that needs to be solved at one location, not get a universal solution.

Now, if you want to produce a **new product** that solves the issue of code signing for teams (and there might be a market for that), that's a different issue altogether (but not one for this place).

Comment: Please read my comment -- there is a difference between modifying a crypto system and modifying an implementation that needs to conform to an existing crypto system. While I respect the fact that not everyone is knowledgeable or experienced enough to safely perform modifications on crypto implementations, certain modifications could be performed under strict circumstances where the general rule that you're referring to doesn't apply. I have taken this into account when I posted my answer, and I have posted it with enough knowledge to conclude that these are in fact safe modifications.

Comment: @JonathanGray I'm afraid I have to disagree. Again, it's not that coding it is really hard, it's that getting it wrong somehow is dreadfully easy. Mess up with the authentication code and you have a hole. mess up how the server checked the hash and you have a hole. And since you're toying with code you're not maintaining, you're also getting vulnerable to regression issue in later development. The general case for this is. don't do it.

Comment: That's where I disagree with you. If you get any part of the hashing implementation wrong, it simply just won't work. Windows will refuse to accept it as a valid digital signature. Same with getting the easier part wrong, which is appending the signature to the end of the file. I've taken quite a bit of knowledge into consideration before posting my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I like Stephane's answer but I'm not satisfied with the fact that it's not exactly feasible in practice without writing your own code. So I have a couple of *possible* alternatives to suggest:

1) Find a completely open source signing tool and modify it to accept a hash as input as opposed to calculating one from the file. Then modify the digital signature appending code to have it sent back to be appended to the real file.

2) You could try using a DLL hook in order to re-route a hashing function of an existing tool (provided you retrieve internal name of the hashing method). Then take the digital signature from the end of the temporary file used and send it back to be appended to the real file.

Comment: No. Please, don't suggest to people they start tinkering with crypto code, especially for a one-off project. It's the road to unmaintained, unmaintainable and vulnerable operation. I'm not saying it can't be done (in fact, I've checked my own code signing tools to see if I could modify them in such a way) but for production work, just don't.

Comment: @Stephane It doesn't seem to me like this would only be used for a one-off project, and I'm not suggesting that people start tinkering with their own crypto code. The risks associated with doing these tasks are artificial anyways, since there really is no way to get it wrong. Basically because of the rigorous testing on the certificate done by Windows itself, if you can get one of these methods to work at all, it should be working properly. It's not even like I'm suggesting for someone to generate their own certificate. This would use an existing cert with existing crypto implementations.

Comment: You can mess that up in a large number of way: since you're not checking the code, just the hash, you need to have a high confidence on where that hash comes from (that's just an example).

Comment: @Stephane That example is invalid; It is outside of the context of the question.

Comment: Not unless that is a one-off project (in which case you can't make assumption of how it'll be used).

Comment: @Stephane The question was whether the hash could be sent to the server as opposed to the file itself. We have to assume that anything related to the security of the hash is outside of the scope of the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33007/discussion-between-stephane-and-jonathan-gray).

Comment: So all the sign tool by default gets the file to a location(Probably its own  memory cache) , generates hash of the file and encrypts using the certificate?

Comment: @GouthamNithyananda Yeah, pretty much. I don't know too much about what exactly the signature consists of, but I do know that it will get appended to the end of the file. There might be some PE headers that get  changed during the signing process too. To be clear though the only thing that gets encrypted is the hash. The rest of the signature I'm pretty sure just consists mostly of your certificate itself.